# How do I override the markdown styling in the content in Storybook?

Tags: css, storybook

Similar to [Styling the Storybook JS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65631078/styling-the-storybook-js) but specifically on the content area.

I want to define the typography I am using which also includes the font.  I'd rather not do any CSS `!important` but what I found was some extra CSS is being added in the generated HTML from Markdown and overriding my stylings.

[image]

I know I can simply use `<Canvas>` but I would rather have the rest of the Storybook follow the style I want.

Comment: Have you tried using changing the [Theme](https://storybook.js.org/docs/react/configure/theming) options?

Comment: Yes but that would mean I am going to duplicate what I did on my CSS with Storybook as well.

Comment: If it's a common style for all your stories then I recommend moving it to storybook

Comment: Also using the theme options override the font sizes rather than keeping the one I want.  The font size is not in the ThemeVars either.